# Как получить чистый url без html тегов

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bs4

Вот код

```
#Парсер v0 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    url=soup.find('meta',{'property':'og:url'})

    print(url)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4980895-askar-mamin-prinyal-uchastie-v.html'
    get_data(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И при выводе он дает мне такой вариант ссылки `<meta content="https://www.zakon.kz/4980895-askar-mamin-prinyal-uchastie-v.html" property="og:url"/>` 
**Как** получить эту ссылку без html тегов

Comment: Попробуйте не `lxml`, а `html.parser` использовать: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`. Результат должен быть такой же, но не будет зависимости от внешней либы `lxml`

Comment: @gil9red А я бы советовал `lxml`. На моей практике `html.parser` часто не справлялся со сложным, возможно, частично невалидным кодом. А в `lxml` предусмотрено несколько оптимизаций, которые очень помогают. Недавно на SO был вопрос, где решением была просто смена парсера на `lxml`, хотя код был написан на валидном `HTML 5`. Но это только моё субъективное мнение. Если результат с использованием `html.parser` будет тот же, то Вы правы, нет необходимости тянуть лишнюю зависимость.

Comment: сейчас проверим с использованием `htmlparser`

Comment: @nomnoms12, вы правы, что проблемы всегда могут быть :) но у меня пока с `html.parser` проблем не было: https://github.com/search?q=user%3Agil9red+%22html.parser%22&type=Code :)

Comment: @gil9red Какой интересный у Вас репозиторий, столько всего! Пиар удался :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить атрибут тега, используя нотацию с квадратными скобками: `[]`.

Замените `print(url)` на `print(url['content'])` для того чтобы напечатать только ссылку.

***Пример:***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    url=soup.find('meta',{'property':'og:url'})

    print(url['content'])

def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4980895-askar-mamin-prinyal-uchastie-v.html'
    get_data(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
https://www.zakon.kz/4980895-askar-mamin-prinyal-uchastie-v.html
```

Comment: А можно ли делать так в `return`?

Comment: @r4khic Как именно? Думаю, что можно.

Comment: `print(url['content'])` -> `return url['content']`, `(get_data(get_html(url)))` -> `print(get_data(get_html(url)))`

Comment: вот так `def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    url=soup.find('meta',{'property':'og:url'})  return([url])`

Comment: @r4khic Конечно, можно. Даже нужно.

Comment: А можете уточнить почему  в `print(url['content'])`  внутри url именно content?

Comment: @r4khic, потому что ссылка находится в атрибуте `content`: `<meta content="https://www.zakon.kz/4980895-askar-mamin-...`, а в переменную `url` попадет элемент `meta`

Comment: Хорошо,благодарю!